# How to extract the property from array of objects matching the specific characters (contains query)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have any array of object having properties id and title.I want to get the ids of all objects which contains the characters entered by user in title properties

```
>[{ID: 3, Title: "License 1"},
{ID: 4, Title: "License 2"},
{ID: 36, Title: "License 3"},
{ID: 37, Title: "License 4"},
{ID: 38, Title: "sense 4"}]
```

this the sample array if user enters lic it should return me n array 
a=[3,4,36,37]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@match) as well as [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to match the character search:

```
const arr = [{ ID: 3, Title: 'License 1' }, ... ];
const query = 'lic';
const reg = new RegExp('.*' + query + '.*', 'gi');

arr.filter((x) => x.ID.match(reg)).map((x) => x.ID);
// [3, 4, 36, 37, ...]
```

Comment: it is giving below error
angular.min.js:107 TypeError: x.match is not a function
    at dashboard-acquisition.component.js:45
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at r.licensorSearch (dashboard-acquisition.component.js:45)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:1), <anonymous>:4:233)
    at pagination.directive.js:72
    at r.$eval (angular.min.js:133)
    at r.$apply (angular.min.js:134)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (pagination.directive.js:70)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)

Comment: woops, forgot to make the match based on the `ID` property - I've edited the answer

Comment: resolved...just replaced x.match() to x.Title.match() and it is working as expected. Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop through the array and add the items to a new array.

```js
  var i;
    var array = [{ID: 3, Title: "License 1"},
    {ID: 4, Title: "License 2"},
    {ID: 36, Title: "License 3"},
    {ID: 37, Title: "License 4"},
    {ID: 38, Title: "sense 4"}]


    var lic = [];

    for (i = 0;i < array.length; i++){
        lic.push(array[i].ID);
    }

    console.log(lic);
```

Comment: Does this provide the matching criteria described in the original post?

Comment: I misread his initial question, as it wasn't very clear upon first glance. I'm not sure the immediate downvote was necessary. I'll adjust the answer.